# A GCD summation $\sum_{\gcd(i,n)=1} \gcd(i-1,n)$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

Let $$\ n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3}\ldots$$ where $p_1,p_2\ldots$ are prime factors of $n$.

> Show that
>   $$\sum_{i=1,\,\gcd(i,n)=1}^n \gcd(i-1,n) = \prod_{} (a_i+1)(p_i-1)p_i^{a_i-1}.$$

I was able to prove it for $n$ having only one prime factor, but I don't know how to proceed for the general case. Assume $\gcd(0,n)=n$.

Comment: You need to show this sum is a multiplicative function of $n$ - that is, if $f(n)$ is your sum and $n,m$ are relatively prime, then $f(nm)=f(n)f(m)$.

Comment: Alternatively, you need to come up with an argument for why the sum is $\tau(n)\phi(n)$, since that is the value on the right, where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ and $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RHS of your identity is $\tau(n)\phi(n)$, which was very suggestive, so I made some google search and I found the what you want to prove is known as [Menon's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#Menon.27s_identity), but in that link there is no proof about this result, however I found another [link](https://karushib.wordpress.com/2015/08/21/menons-identity/) where this identity is proved. The proof only uses elementary number theory.

By the way, Menon's identity has been generalized in different ways. Here are some of them:

1. [Menon’s identity and arithmetical sums representing functions of
   several variables](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.5861v2.pdf)
2. [A generalization of Menon’s identity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2198v2.pdf)
3. [A generalization of Menon's identity with respect to a set of polynomials](http://www.emis.de/journals/PM/53f3/pm53f306.pdf)
4. [Another generalization of the gcd-sum function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.1020.pdf)